# Any way to shorten this Powershell line? (shorthand)

Tags: powershell

Just looking to see if anyone knows of a way to shorten this powershell line:

```
gci -Recurse -path $temp | ? {(".jpg",".png" -eq $_.extension -and $_ -match 'this' -and $_ -match "that")} | mi -Destination ($Images) -Force
```

The line is in this code:

```
$Temp = "F:\Temp-Images"
$Images = "F:\Images\"
gci -Recurse -path $Temp | ? {(".jpg",".png" -eq $_.extension -and $_ -match 'this' -and $_ -match "that")} | mi -Destination ($Images) -Force
```

The script is meant to look in a folder ($Temp), find any files with the extension .jpg **or** .png, AND that have **both** the words "this" and "that" in the filename. If it finds a match, it moves the file to the destination folder ($Images)

So if there's a file in "F:\Temp-Images" named "this-that.png", it will get moved to "F:\Images\"

I'm new to PowerShell, so I pieced the above code together via google searches. I don't know if my syntax is great or not, but it's working for me. I'm just wondering if there's a way to shorten the code. For example, is there a way to shorten this?:

```
-and $_ -match 'this' -and $_ -match "that"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which PowerShell version, is there an order in `this` and `that`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shorting as much as possible get's cryptic ;-)

```
$Temp = "F:\Temp-Images\"
$Images = "F:\Images\"
ls $Temp -R -I *.jpg,*.png|?{$_.Name -match 'this.*that|that.*this'}|mi -D ($Images) -Fo
```

To test I'd append `-WhatIf` or `-Confirm` to Move-Item

Comment: Wow, that is cryptic! :) But very cool. I've give it a try. Thanks!! Question this part: `'this.*that|that.*this'` - Is it repeated in reverse because it's sensitive to the order of the words?

Comment: This is a Regular Expression (as always with -match) the vertical bar here means or so the order doesn't matter `.*` matches anything in between.